# How to compare elements consisting of two values? (pareto optimum)

Tags: python-3.x

I am pretty new to Python and I want to perform some sort of Pareto optimum. It is somewhat difficult to explain, so I hope my question will be clear enough to understand.

I have the following model which consists of a list of 5 doors (list: ‘doors’) and each door contains two costs (shown in dictionary ‘cost’): [travel distance, delay]. I would like to compare the costs of each door with the costs of another door. However, there is no dominant cost. This means I want a list of doors with the best solution (minimize cost) for both costs.

```
doors = ['D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5']

# cost: [travel distance, delay]
cost = {
'D1': [150, 0],
'D2': [160, 0],
'D3': [170, 1],
'D4': [140, 2],
'D5': [150, 0]
}

def test(doors):
    for s in doors:
        for d in doors:
            if s != d:
                if cost[s][0] < cost[d][0] and cost[s][1] < cost[d][1]:
                    doors.remove(d)
    return doors

print(test(doors))
```

For instance: D1, D2, D5 both have delay cost of 0. If I would only look for the door with minimum delay cost all three doors will do. However, D2 has a travel distance of 160 which is bigger than 150. Therefore, you would never choose D2 (compared to D1 and D5), since it consists of the same delay value and a worse travel distance value. So we would like D2 to be removed from the list.

For travel distance cost, you would choose D4 since it has the lowest travel distance: 140. Although it has the highest delay, there is no door which outperforms D4 due to the low travel distance.

So eventually I want a list with doors for which one of the cost is minimum with the best value for the other cost. 
Based on this, I would like to have the following output:

best_doors = [‘D1’, ‘D4’,  ‘D5’].

In my model, I try to compare both costs for two different doors and remove a door if both costs are higher than the costs of the other door, but it does not give me the output I want.

I understand that my function is probably too simple to solve this problem but I don’t know how to solve this otherwise. Does someone have any idea how to solve this? I already looked on the internet to several websites, but nothing seems to really solve my problem.

Your help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest would be to make a `Door` class

## Doors class

```
class Door():
    def __init__(self, name, distance, delay):
        self.name = name
        self.distance = distance
        self.delay = delay

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return (self.distance > other.distance and self.delay >= other.delay) or \
    (self.distance >= other.distance and self.delay > other.delay)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Door(name=%s, distance=%i, delay=%i'% (self.name, self.distance, self.delay)
```

Note the double comparison  (`>`, `>=`) and (`>=`, `>`). With only (`>`, `>`) there would be no difference between `D1` and `D2`

## generating the samples

Here I use a set, a `dict` would work too with slight adaptations

```
doors_orig = set()
for d, c in cost.items():
    doors_orig.add(Door(d, *c))
```

> doors_orig

```
{Door(name=D4, distance=140, delay=2,
 Door(name=D1, distance=150, delay=0,
 Door(name=D5, distance=150, delay=0,
 Door(name=D2, distance=160, delay=0,
 Door(name=D3, distance=170, delay=1}
```

## The actual comparisons

Then you can use `itertools.permutations` to generate all possible combinations. Check whether that combination is still a subset of the possible best doors and compare them. Discard of it is absolutely larger.

```
doors_perm = doors_orig.copy()
comb = itertools.permutations(doors_perm, 2)

for d1, d2 in comb:
    if {d1, d2} <= doors_perm and (d1 > d2):
        doors_perm.discard(d1)
```

> doors_perm

```
{Door(name=D4, distance=140, delay=2,
 Door(name=D1, distance=150, delay=0,
 Door(name=D5, distance=150, delay=0}
```

Whether the `{d1, d2} <= doors_perm` is necessary depends on the relative performance of the subset check and the comparison.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, this is what I am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that this may not fully answer your question but I hope it would lead you in the correct direction as this is not a (too) trivial problem (and this is too long to be a comment).

One way to approach this would be to give each cost a "weight" ie how much does it contribute to the decision whether or not to choose a specific door.

Usually this is done by coming up with a formula that appropriately describes the weight of each cost.

In the bellow example I used a formula that gives the distance a weight of 1 and  the `delay` a weight of 5.

```
cost = {
'D1': [150, 0],
'D2': [160, 0],
'D3': [170, 1],
'D4': [140, 2],
'D5': [150, 0]
}

def cost_function(x):
    # x here is a tuple of the form (door_name, [travel distance, delay])
    return x[1][0] + x[1][1] * 5

print(sorted(cost.items(), key=cost_function))
# [('D1', [150, 0]), ('D4', [140, 2]), ('D5', [150, 0]),
#  ('D2', [160, 0]), ('D3', [170, 1])]
```

This cost function achieves the specific order you wanted.